# JSON parse error on comments system

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently working on a comments system, it was all working fine yesterday then today I started getting errors. I am using json to post the comment straight away without a page reload. the error I'm getting is "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character". I have to reload the page in order for the comment to show up.

Also when I had it working, I couldn't figure out how to insert the date, it works on page reload coming from the database. It was showing up as 0 before page reload.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//this will fire once the page has been fully loaded
$('#comment-post-btn').click(function(){
comment_post_btn_click();
});
});

function comment_post_btn_click()
{

//text within textarea which the person has entered
var _comment = $('#comment-post-text').val();
var _userId = $('#userId').val();
var _userName = $('#userName').val();
var _PlaceId = $('#PlaceId').val();
var _date = $('.date').val();


if(_comment.length > 0 && _userId != null)
{
    //proceed with our ajax callback
    $('.comment-insert-container').css('border' , '1px solid #e1e1e1');

    $.post("ajax/comment_insert.php" ,
        {
            task : "comment_insert",
            userId : _userId,
            comment : _comment,
            PlaceId : _PlaceId,
            date : _date
        }
    )
    .error(

        function( )
        {
            console.log( "Error: " );
        })
    .success(

        function(data)
        {
            //success
            //task: insert html into the ul / li
            comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
            console.log("responseText: " +data);
        }

    );


    console.log( _comment + " UserName: " + _userName + " User Id: " + _userId + " PlaceId: " + _PlaceId + " date: " + _date);
}
else
{
    $('.comment-insert-container').css('border' , '1px solid #ff0000');
    console.log("the text area was empty");

}


//removes text from text area
$('#comment-post-text').val("");
}

function comment_insert(data)
{
var t = '';
t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_'+data.comment.comment_id+'">';
t += '<div class="user-img">';
    t += '<img src="'+data.user.profile_img+'" class="user-img-pic" />';
t += '</div>';
    t += '<div class="comment-body">';
        t += '<h3 class="username-field">'+data.user.userName+'</h3>';
        t += '<p class="date">'+data.comment.date+'</p>';
    t += '</div>';
        t += '<div class="comment-text">'+data.comment.comment+'</div>';
            t += '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
                t += '<ul>';
                    t += '<li id="'+data.comment.comment_id+'" class="delete-btn">x</li>';
                t += '</ul>';
            t += '</div>';
t += '</li>';

$('.comments-holder-ul').prepend(t);
add_delete_handlers();

}
```

Comment: You should show how you are building the JSON on the server side and perhaps include an example.  This sounds like an issue of invalid JSON, so posting the client-side code isn't likely to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever `ajax/comment_insert.php` returns is not valid JSON. Use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) to check the syntax.

Comment: wow! It told me I needed a space between function and () I tried that and it worked. I feel so stupid, But I don't understand how it was working fine yesterday? strange! do you know how I can insert the date correctly?

Comment: @cameron9584 Please accept the answer then, thanks! I don't really understand what the issue with the date is, consider creating a new question.

Comment: I have done now I couldn't accept it within 5 minutes. Sorry.